# ASP.NET: How to make this table editable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, grid

I have been following this tutorial: http://w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_repeater3

I have been able to complete this tutorial, but I wanted to take it to the next level by making this grid editable and I am not sure how to do this.

Is there a way to make the grid editable?

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<script  runat="server">
sub Page_Load
if Not Page.IsPostBack then
 dim mycdcatalog=New DataSet
mycdcatalog.ReadXml(MapPath("cdcatalog.xml"))
cdcatalog.DataSource=mycdcatalog
cdcatalog.DataBind()
end if
end sub
</script>

<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="cdcatalog" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<th align="left">Title</th>
<th align="left">Artist</th>
<th align="left">Company</th>
<th align="left">Price</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("title")%> </td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("artist")%> </td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("company")%> </td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("price")%> </td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<SeparatorTemplate>
<tr>
<td colspan="6"><hr /></td>
</tr>
</SeparatorTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
</form>

</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Use a GridView instead, that renders as a table and has edit-capabilities by default.

Comment: I want to learn how to do it without a .net control like a datagrid/view

Comment: Why? The whole point of the GridView is to make your life easier.

Comment: I guess that noone on here is smart enough

Comment: @Raja: haha nice try. Kind of sad though

Comment: w3schools.com is a horrible resource. They shouldn't even suggest the crap code you've copied from them. I second every suggestion of using a `GridView` instead. Once you graduate `GridView` school then you can move on to an AJAX-powered grid.

Comment: I will insult the people who would consider helping me into actually helping me, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

How about jQuery? There's a great plugin right here: [jQuery Grid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). When you get there, you want to look for Editing Rows.

If that is not what you're looking for, you should consider using GridView.

If still, that's not what you're looking for, maybe you should just try it manually with what you have learned so far in the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are not afraid to experiment with third-party AJAX grids, consider using the [Telerik one](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) which offers a plethora of data editing capabilities and more.